# Missing .sln file in C# / vb.net apps?

Tags: visual-studio, solution

I am working with source code  (C# and vb.net apps). Many of the projects do not have a solution file (.sln file).  I would like to know (which version of Visual Studio) these projects were coded/developed in?  Is there a way to determine what Version of Visual Studio (2019, 2022 etc.) these projects were coded in without a .sln file?

Comment: The .csproj and .vbproj files might have _some_ of this information, but I don't know if its guaranteed to be accurate.

Comment: Thanks Timothy.  Looking in the .**proj files I am able to see references and plenty of valuable info.  I think, perhaps, if I had not mentioned .sln file that people would be directing to the .sln file to determine which version Visual Studio the projected was coded in.  Personally, I find it odd that the .sln files are missing from these repositories. I  think .sln files are important / provide metadata about the project